# Can I change the loadout of a started mission?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I went on a mission (Specifically, Karma) and clicked the default build without putting much thought into it. But the default build sucks. There's a great need for corrected loadout, but this far I can't find how to **completely** restart mission, including the "Change Loadout" part. Is that even possible, or do I have to stagger through the mission with that poor choice and then restart it with different weapons? That's pretty strange.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but when the mission starts you can not edit the loud out, at the most you can pick up guns from the floor.