# How to abort mission to change loadout?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I'm resuming story on *Suffer with me*. I don't believe I've started this mission before finishing with the game the other day. When choosing to Resume Campaing I'm immediately in the intro to the mission. Skipping that places me on the boat.

How do I get out of that so that I can change loadout from default? If I choose "Save and quit", then go back to campaing - after clicking resume I'm back to intro and then loop starts.

Option to rewind is available on "Fallen Angel", so I lose all StrikeForce missions progress.

Comment: It's been a minute since I've play BO2, but on the main screen, isn't there a mission select option?  If there is, that's how you would have to do it.  Exit the Campaign mission, go into Mission Select and select that mission.

Comment: @KevinFischer - that's not possible: 1. Exiting mission also exits Campaign. You can go back to campaign, but that throws you back into mission. 2. Mission Select - there explicitly states it will not change the gameplay in campaign. Unless taking option on rewind to that mission, losing all progress since then.

Comment: What I would do in your situation is to beat that level, then go back and do it again with the loadout you want.  I think that might be your only option at this point.

Comment: @KevinFischer - I think that you're correct. That's what I ended up doing  after trying all I could think of.

Answer (score -1):

When the mission starts, you cannot change the loadout, though you can pick up guns from the floor.

There's a question like this: [Can I change the loadout of a started mission?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183321/can-i-change-the-loadout-of-a-started-mission)

Comment: They're not asking how to change the loadout in the mission.  They're asking how to *abort* the mission so they can do so.